# FTP Changing PGP File During Transfer in C#

Tags: c#, file, file-upload, ftp, pgp

I have PGP files that I've verified as being valid, but at some point during the FTP upload, they become corrupt.  When retrieved, I get an error message stating "Found no PGP information in these file(s)."

For what it's worth, the PGP is version 6.5.8, but I think that this is unimportant, as the files seem alright before they're uploaded.

My code is as follows for the file transfer, is there a setting or field that I've missed?

```
static void FTPUpload(string file)
    {
        FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://ftp.itginc.com" + "/" + Path.GetFileName(file));

        request.UseBinary = true;
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ApplicationSettings["Username"], ApplicationSettings["Password"]);

        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(file);

        byte[] fileContents = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sr.ReadToEnd());
        sr.Close();

        request.ContentLength = fileContents.Length;

        Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();

        requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
        requestStream.Close();

        FtpWebResponse resp = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        Console.WriteLine("Upload file complete, status {0}", resp.StatusDescription);

        resp.Close();
        string[] filePaths= Directory.GetFiles(tempPath);
        foreach (string filePath in filePaths) 
            File.Delete(filePath);
    }
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Does this happen always?

Comment: Yes- it uploads approximately 100 files, and they all have the same problem.

Comment: I thought PGP encoded data as text?  Shouldn't UseBinary be set to false?

Comment: @Jason binary is default mode, and you can optionally "armor" (base64-encode) the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmmmm try not reading it into a byte array and instead doing something like this

```
        using (var reader = File.Open(source, FileMode.Open))
        {
            var ftpStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            reader.CopyTo(ftpStream);
            ftpStream.Close();
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

PGP encodes data to binary stream, so your reading it via StreamReader and UTF8 probably breaks the data. FTP is unlikely to alter the data as you explicitly binary mode (though UseBinary is true by default so your setting should not do anything at all).

Comment: So you're suggesting I use BinaryReader, and what would I replace UTF8 with?

Comment: @seanvdh don't use StreamReader where you can go with stream. StreamReader can bring only troubles.